# How does comparison of a slice with an array work in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

Why would `[1,1] == &[1,1]` not even compile (presumably because they're different types), yet the following snippet compiles and runs fine.

```
let a: [i32; 100] = [1; 100];
let b: &[i32] = &a[1..3];
if b == [1, 1] { // comparison with &[1, 1] works as well
    println!("it works"); // this does get printed
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now, arrays in Rust are somewhat special because Rust lacks type-level integers. You can't write a function `fn f<T, N>(array: &[T; N])`. Likewise, you can't implement a trait which is generic over `N`.

The standard library provides some trait implementations for array lengths ranging from 0 to 32 to mitigate this issue, which is why `b == [1,1]` works. There's an implementation of the trait `PartialEq` for this case:

```
impl<'a, 'b, A, B> PartialEq<[A; 2]> for &'b [B] 
where B: PartialEq<A>
```

However, the trait `PartialEq<&[A; 2]>` is not implemented for `[B; 2]`. Thus you cannot compare `[1, 1]` and `&[1, 1]`. `b == [1; 33]` will not work in your example too, as there's no implementations for arrays longer than 32 elements.

But there's ongoing effort to bring type-level integers into Rust. [RFC 2000](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2000) is the latest proposal.

For the time being  you can rely on implicit conversion from reference to the array to reference to slice. Like this

```
fn f<T>(slice: &[T]) {}

f(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);
```