# Expected a slice, found an array when asserting they are equal

Tags: types, rust, slice

I'm trying to assert that two slices are equal, but one of the slices is being interpreted as an array:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Error {
    TooBig,
}

type Bytes = [u8];

struct Fixed {
    length: u32,
}

impl<'a> Fixed {
    pub fn new(length: u32) -> Fixed {
        Fixed { length: length }
    }

    pub fn length(&self) -> u32 {
        self.length
    }

    pub fn encode(&self, decoded: &'a Bytes) -> Result<&'a Bytes, Error> {
        if decoded.len() > self.length() as usize {
            Err(Error::TooBig)
        } else {
            Ok(&decoded)
        }
    }

    pub fn decode(&self, decoded: &'a Bytes) -> Result<&'a Bytes, Error> {
        if decoded.len() > self.length() as usize {
            Err(Error::TooBig)
        } else {
            Ok(&decoded)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn fixed_0() {
        let length = 0;
        let fixed = Fixed::new(length);
        let encoded = [];
        let decoded = [];
        assert_eq!(fixed.length(), length);
        assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&decoded), Ok(&encoded));
        assert_eq!(fixed.decode(&encoded), Ok(&decoded));
        assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&[1]), Err(Error::TooBig));
    }

    #[test]
    fn fixed_1() {
        let length = 1;
        let fixed = Fixed::new(length);
        let encoded: [u8; 1] = [1];
        let decoded: [u8; 1] = [1];
        assert_eq!(fixed.length(), length);
        assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&decoded).unwrap(), &encoded);
        assert_eq!(fixed.decode(&encoded).unwrap(), &decoded);
    }
}
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/aakilfernandes/32e77bb1f23b4ba3d005b713d59c3ca5#file-src-fixed-rs-L52-L53)

And here's my errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:49:9
   |
49 |         assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&decoded), Ok(&encoded));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found array of 0 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<&[u8], Error>`
              found type `std::result::Result<&[_; 0], _>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:50:9
   |
50 |         assert_eq!(fixed.decode(&encoded), Ok(&decoded));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found array of 0 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<&[u8], Error>`
              found type `std::result::Result<&[u8; 0], _>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

My reading of the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/array.html) leads me to believe that by using `&`, I should be creating a slice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example can be reduced:

```
fn example(input: Result<&[u8], ()>) {
    assert_eq!(input, Ok(&[]));
}
```

A reference to an array is a reference to an array, not a slice. In many contexts, a reference to an array may be *coerced* to a slice, but not everywhere. This is a case where it cannot.

Use more explicit slicing syntax instead:

```
assert_eq!(input, Ok(&[][..]));
```

See also:

- [assert_eq!(a,b) fails to compile for slices while assert!(a == b) works fine](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51206)
- [What's the most idiomatic way to test two Options for equality when they contain values which can be tested for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30429801/155423)
- [How does comparison of a slice with an array work in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44351328/155423)